# Sum on a left join SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables I wish to join on lets say table a and table b.  Table b has many rows to table a's, table b contains prices (effectively a shopping basket).  So what I want is all records from table a and the sum of the price from table b.  I have tried

```
select a.*, sum(b.ach_sell) from bookings a 
left join pricing_line b on b.bookings = a.id
```

However this obviously doesn't do as I wish, it ends up with the total sum of all ach_sell (so one record is returned).  Would someone kindly offer me a solution which would help? right now I am doing it programatically and I am pretty sure it could be done in SQL?

Comment: is it practical to do a union?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your direction is right, just add a group by clause to separate the a.id's, something like this:

```
select a.id, sum(b.ach_sell) 
from bookings a  
  left join pricing_line b 
on b.bookings = a.id 
group by a.id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.*, sum(b.ach_sell) as sum_column 
from bookings a 
  left join pricing_line b
         on b.bookings = a.id
group by a.id
```

Every time you use funcions of aggregation (`SUM`, `COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`) you need to group by some other set of fields (tipically the id) on which you don't apply an aggregation function.

Answer (score 2):

Group on the fields from the bookings table:

```
select a.this, a.that, sum(b.ach_sell)
from bookings a 
left join pricing_line b on b.bookings = a.id
group by a.this, a.that
```

Comment: I'd add "sum(b.ach_sell) as summed_column" for easier addressing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY` something if you don't want just a single result. Possibly?

```
select a.*, 
       sum(b.ach_sell) as ach_sell
from bookings a 
left join pricing_line b on b.bookings = a.id
GROUP BY  a.id
```

Other RDBMSs would insist on you having the entire column list in the `GROUP BY` but MySQL doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many columns in select.

Like this:

```
SELECT
    co.checkOutOrderID,
    com.companyCode,
    sd.serviceDispatchCode,
    cu.customerName,
    com.companySimp,
    ISNULL(SUM (sdlp.partsModelPrice * sdlp.partsModelNum), 0) AS total
FROM
    checkoutorder co
LEFT JOIN 
    servicedispatchorder sd ON sd.serviceDispatchID = co.serviceDispatchID
LEFT JOIN 
    customer cu ON cu.customerID = co.customerID
LEFT JOIN 
    company com ON com.companyID = co.companyID
LEFT JOIN 
    servicedispatchlinkparts sdlp ON sdlp.serviceDispatchID = sd.serviceDispatchID
GROUP BY
    sd.serviceDispatchID, co.checkOutOrderID, 
    com.companyCode, sd.serviceDispatchCode,
    cu.customerName, com.companySimp
```