# Select sum and inner join

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables

- `Bills`: `id amount reference`
- `Transactions`: `id reference amount`

The following SQL query

```
SELECT 
   *,
   (SELECT SUM(amount) 
    FROM transactions 
    WHERE transactions.reference = bils.reference) AS paid
FROM bills
GROUP BY id HAVING paid<amount
```

was meant to some rows from table `Bills`, adding a column `paid` with the sum of amount of related transactions.

However, it only works when there is at least one transaction for each bill. Otherwise, no line for a transaction-less bill is returned.

Probably, that's because I should have done an inner join!

So I try the following:

```
SELECT 
   *,
   (SELECT SUM(transactions.amount) 
    FROM transactions 
    INNER JOIN bills ON transactions.reference = bills.reference) AS paid
FROM bills
GROUP BY id 
HAVING paid < amount
```

However, this returns the same value of paid for all rows! What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a left join instead of a subquery:

```
select b.id, b.amount, b.paid, sum(t.amount) as transactionamount
from bills b
left join transactions t on t.reference = b.reference
group by b.id, b.amount, b.paid
having b.paid < b.amount
```

Edit:
To compare the sum of transactions to the amount, handle the null value that you get when there are no transactions:

```
having isnull(sum(t.amount), 0) < b.amount
```

Comment: But there is no "paid" column in `Bills`, this has to be defined as the sum of amount of transactions. If I try to modify it to correct that, I still get only `Bills` row with at least one transaction.

Comment: @Klaus: I see, that's where you got that from... The sum will be null if there are no transactions, so you would need to handle that. See code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the `ifnull` (not `isnull`) and left join did the trick!

Comment: @Klaus: Ah, you didn't specify what brand of database you are using. SQL Server, which I normally work with, uses `isnull`, not `ifnull`.

Comment: what if the main table is t, and the amount you need to sum is being queried from b?

Comment: @AtaSagun: That sounds like the exact same situation, with just the table names switched.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `RIGHT JOIN` to include all bill rows.

**EDIT**
So the final query will be

```
SELECT 
   *,
   (SELECT SUM(transactions.amount) 
    FROM transactions 
    WHERE transactions.reference = bills.reference) AS paid
FROM bills
WHERE paid < amount
```

Comment: That will return the sum of all transactions for all bills.

Comment: There is still the same problem as in my second attempt, as @Guffa describes.

Comment: What if you replace "INNER JOIN bills ON" with "WHERE"

Comment: And assuming that "id" is the PK of your bills table, you don't need to "GROUP BY id" and replace HAVING with WHERE as well.

Comment: You cannot do a WHERE clause on `paid`.

Answer (score 0):

I knows this thread is old, but I came here today because I encountering the same problem.

Please see another post with same question:
[Sum on a left join SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782026/sum-on-a-left-join-sql)

As the answer says, use GROUP BY on the left table. This way you get all the records out from left table, and it sums the corresponding rows from right table.

Try to use this:

```
SELECT
   *,
  SUM(transactions.sum)
FROM
   bills
RIGHT JOIN
   transactions
ON
   bills.reference = transactions.reference
WHERE
   transactions.sum > 0
GROUP BY
   bills.id
```